# How to check a website for SSLv2 or SSLv3?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

I'm trying on a list of websites and trying to get the types of protocols that each website supports. However, I'm only able to retrieve from TLSv1 onwards.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
osobj = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv3_METHOD)
sock.connect((host, int(port)))
oscon = SSL.Connection(osobj, sock)
oscon.set_tlsext_host_name(host.encode())
oscon.set_connect_state()
oscon.do_handshake()

protocol = oscon.get_protocol_version_name() # If website supports SSLv2, it should return 'SSLv2'
```

I understand that *openssl* deprecated SSLv2 and SSLv3.

How can I then get the whole list of protocols supported by a website?

Comment: You can use [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html)

Comment: How can I do that in  python?

Comment: @kai run `nmap` without Python. If you really have to use Python then you have standard module `subprocess`.

Comment: maybe use portal [SSL labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)

Comment: see more: [10 Online Tool to Test SSL, TLS and Latest Vulnerability](https://geekflare.com/ssl-test-certificate/)

Comment: I can't use other tools except for python. Looks like using subprocess and extract the results from python is the way forward.

Comment: if you can't use other tools then you can't use `nmap` :)

Comment: maybe you should search in Google more information and check source code in some tools - ie. [pysslscan](https://pypi.org/project/sslscan/) or [sslyze](https://tools.kali.org/information-gathering/sslyze)

Answer (score 0):

To check the TLS protocol version that was negotiated in your connection you can call `oscon.get_protocol_version_name()`. To prevent from using SSLv2/v3 you can use flags `OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2` and `OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2` when setting connection options `set_options()`. If you need to restrict your connection to use only SSLv2/v3 - set options `OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1, OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_1, OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_2, OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_3`. By paying with those options you can fully control TLS version of your connection.

Here's how I would use it in your code fragment:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
osobj = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
osobj.set_options(OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1 | OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_2 | OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_3)
sock.connect(("google.com", int(443)))
oscon = SSL.Connection(osobj, sock)
oscon.set_connect_state()

try:
    oscon.do_handshake()
    print("SSL v2/v3 supported")
except OpenSSL.SSL.Error as err:
    if err.args[0][0][2] == "no protocols available":
        print("SSL v2/v3 is not supported")
```

Comment: I tried with those options, but I either get "No Such protocol" or "context must be a Context instance". 
`osobj = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv2_METHOD).set_options(OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1 | OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_2 | OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_3)`

Comment: I added code fragment to my answer above. Are you sure your openssl installation supports SSLv2/v3? The same question for your TLS server.

Comment: My openssl installation does not supports SSLv2/v3.
How can I enable the support for it? Or which version of openssl supports it?
I'm using pyopenssl v19.1.0, where the base layer openssl already deprecated SSLv2/v3.

Comment: TLS server is supporting SSLv2/v3, as nmap results showed it supports (same with ssllabs results)

Comment: Try taking some old pyOpenSSL version. Here's the list https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/blob/master/doc/ChangeLog_old.txt

Comment: Even if using older version of pyOpenSSL, it still doesn't work. I think I need to rebuild OpenSSL with a custom build python.
https://superuser.com/questions/1488780/compiling-python3-7-with-a-custom-openssl-version

Comment: Right, it could be a good idea to rebuilt OpenSSL with SSLv2/v3 support and then check.